# Regex doesn't allow two consecutive dashes together (golang)

Tags: regex

Can you help me please, my regex shouldn't allow two or more consecutive dashes together(--). All other characters are allowed. Unfortunately negative lookahead doesnt work in golang

I have regex here `^[a-z]+(?:[-'\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$`, but there is several conditions. I need only non-repeating dash

Comment: Then move the other non-word chars to the alpha character classes, `^[a-z\s']+(?:-[a-zA-Z\s']+)*$`

Comment: I mean I need a regular expression that allows any characters except repeating dashes (--)

Comment: Then use `^[^-]+(?:-[^-]+)*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you! this regex works ^[^-]+(?:-[^-]+)*$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^[^-]+(?:-[^-]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Ya7pc/1). To allow leading/trailing hyphens:

```
^-?[^-]+(?:-[^-]+)*-?$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^-]+` - one or more chars other than `-`
- `(?:-[^-]+)*` - zero or more sequences of a `-` and then one or more chars other than `-`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this: `.*[-]{2,}.*`